# xargs : using same argument in multiple commands

Tags: shell, command-line, xargs

Am trying to write a one-liner that can probe the output of `df -h` and alert when one of the partitions is out [or almost] of space. It's the part using xargs that kicking me in the ass now...

```
echo 95 | xargs -n1 -I{} [ {} -ge 95 ] && echo "No Space on disk {}% full -- remove old backups please"
```

How can i make the second {} show "95" too?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That `&&` is not part of the `xargs` command, it's a completely separate invocation. I think you'll want to execute a shell explicitly:

```
echo 95 | xargs -I_percent sh -c '[ "$1" -ge 95 ] && echo "No Space on disk $1% full -- remove old backups please"' sh _percent
```

Note also that I'm using `_percent` instead of `{}` to avoid extra quoting headaches with the shell. It's not a shell variable; still just an `xargs` replacement string.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way, which is more readable, is to define a separate function which contains all your other commands and then call that function with `xargs` in a sub-shell.

Hence, for example:

```
myfunc(){
  [ "$1" -ge 95 ] && echo "No Space on disk $1% full -- remove old backups please"
  echo "Another command echoing $1"
}

export -f myfunc

echo 95 | xargs -n1 -I_percent -- sh -c 'myfunc "_percent"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the ***`sh`*** option mentioned and enclose the command in single quotes as show below with an extra equivalent ***`if`*** version:

```
#Your example
echo 95 | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c '[ {} -ge 95 ] && echo "No Space on disk {}% full -- remove old backups please"'

#if equivalent
echo 95 | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'if [ {} -ge 95 ]; then echo "No Space on disk {}% full -- remove old backups please"; fi'
```

Using `xargs` with **alias** in ***`-I`*** option for better readability

```
echo 95 | xargs -n1 -IusedSpace sh -c 'if [ usedSpace -ge 95 ]; then echo "No Space on disk usedSpace% full -- remove old backups please"; fi'
```

With **if** and chain as many command as You wish separated by semicolon ***;***  below ***example with 2 and 4 commands chained***

```
# 2 independent commands
echo 95 | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'if [ {} -ge 95 ]; then echo "No Space on disk {}% full -- remove old backups please"; echo "Value processed {}"; fi'
# 4 independent commands
echo 95 | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'if [ {} -ge 95 ]; then echo "No Space on disk {}% full -- remove old backups please"; echo "Space left on disk $( expr 100 - {})%"; echo "Space used {}%"; echo "Value processed {}"; fi'
```

I added the `else` case in your example, It prints the left disk space

```
#If with else block
echo 80 | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'if [ {} -ge 95 ]; then echo "No Space on disk {}% full -- remove old backups please"; else echo "Space left on disk $( expr 100 - {})%"; fi'

#Equivalent
echo 80 | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c '[ {} -ge 95 ] && echo "No Space on disk {}% full -- remove old backups please"; [ {} -ge 95 ] || echo "Space left on disk $( expr 100 - {})%"'
```

Another modification could be isolate the 95 percent of limit usage in a variable as show below:

```
echo 96 | xargs -n1 -IusedSpace sh -c 'usageLimit=95; if [ usedSpace -ge ${usageLimit} ]; then echo "No Space on disk usedSpace% full -- remove old backups please"; else echo "Space left on disk $( expr 100 - usedSpace)%"; fi'
```

Happy scripting!!!
@enrique