# chmod and chown at the same time?

Tags: bash, shell-script, permissions, ownership

I have a script I'm running to fix file ownership and permissions after an rsync. Questions of the optimal way to do my task aside, I wonder, is there a way to run `chmod` and `chown` at the same time?

In the current iteration of my script, I'm `find`ing files twice.

```
find /var/www/mysite -exec chown  www-data:www-data {} \;
find /var/www/mysite -type f -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

I thought it would be nice if I could change both the permissions and owner/group with a single command. After some googling, I was surprised to learn that such a command, argument, or option doesn't exist.

Can I change both the permissions and ownership at the same time, to avoid `find`ing each file twice?

*Edit* A community edit or post or something suggested that this question is a duplicate of ["Change all folder permissions with 1 command"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349053/change-all-folder-permissions-with-1-command). This question is different because it asks about changing **both** permissions **and** ***ownership*** at the same time, not just permissions.

Comment: you really, really, really don't want all your web files to be 775.

Comment: If your files have permission 755 be aware that a user on the same server (for instance shared hosting) can edit your files. It is better to use 755 for folder and 644 for files.

Comment: @GuyT: That is incorrect. `755` is `rwxr-xr-x`. It doesn't allow modification by anyone other than the owner.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I am sorry, you are correct.

Comment: @OlivierDulac this is for a local development instance inside a vbox vm

Comment: Given that your web files are almost certainly interpreted by some other program (php, ruby, python, perl files, etc.), they don't even need execute permission.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change all folder permissions with 1 command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349053/change-all-folder-permissions-with-1-command)

Comment: Add `-print0` to the end and pipe the filenames into a single instance of **Perl** which can do the the `chmod` and `chown` as simple library calls without starting new processes.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' No it doesn't -- see my edit at the bottom.

Comment: Yeah, but did you look at my *answer* to that other question?  It shows how to run two commands on a directory tree with a single invocation of `find` — which is what you’re asking for. (OK, not exactly the same, but it’s more advanced than jesse_b’s answer to your question, so you should have been able to adapt it.)

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' feel free to post the adapter answer, that fulfills the requirements of this question, as an answer on this question.

Comment: It would be too similar to jesse_b’s answer to be worth posting as a separate answer.

Answer (score 18):

You can pass multiple exec commands:

```
find /var/www/mysite -exec chown www-data:www-data {} \; \
     -type f -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

Comment: @user394 No, you can't, because each predicate (`-type`, `-exec` etc) is a _test_, and there's a logical AND between them (implicitly). You could work out the logic with OR (`-o`) and parentheses. Possibly something like `\( -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \; \) -o \( -type f -exec chmod 775 {} \; \)` etc.

Comment: @user394 In Jesse's code, `chmod` will only ever be executed for regular files (`-type f`) that the preceding `chown` was successful for. If the `chown` _fails_, the `-type f` etc. won't happen, and  the next thing found will be considered instead. (that's how `-exec` can be seen as a test).

Answer (score 10):

You could add the equivalent options to your `rsync` command:

```
rsync <your_options> --chown www-data:www-data --chmod=F775 <source> <destination>
```

You can use prefix `F` in `--chmod` for files and `D` for directories.

Comment: I'm guessing the user UID database is not the same between both hosts.  This would be one reason for using ldap or another central repository of UID info on a network.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness **xargs** can do all sorts of interesting things in pipelines too.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I VAR -- sh -c 'chmod 775 "VAR" && chown www-data:www-data "VAR" '
```

This produces a stream of filenames (not directory names) with nulls for separators, so deals with spaces in filenames.

`-0` tells xargs to separate inputs on the null.
`-I VAR` says to use `VAR` as the "variable name" rather than `{}`
`--` and everything after it is what to run for each line

This may be more readable, but it will be starting a new shell for each run of the double-barrelled command.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958689/running-multiple-commands-with-xargs
- [xargs : using same argument in multiple commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56734/xargs-using-same-argument-in-multiple-commands)

Comment: Never embed the text substituted by `xargs` inside the shell code (or code to any interpreter for that matters), as that makes it a code injection vulnerability. Use `-exec sh -c 'for file do chmod 775 "$file" && chown www-data: "$file"; done' sh {} +`. `xargs` is rarely useful to process `find`'s output.

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about `find`ing each file twice, you may also want to worry about the number of forks that running a combination of commands via xargs would produce.

People often forget that perl has equivalents for many of these basic shell commands.  Here's one way I'd do this (tested):

```
find | perl -lne 'chown 1001,1001, $_; -d $_ ? chmod(0755, $_) : chmod(0644, $_)'
```

You'd have to use the *numeric* uid, gid, and mode, but think about this: **this does not fork at all** (beyond the one `find` and the one `perl`).

And you don't need to know a lot of perl to grok it either.

The chown and chmod are clear enough.  `-d` is the same as in shell's `[` or the `test` command, and the ternary operator `foo ? bar : baz` is not unique to perl.  (*As a bonus, you get to use different modes for directories and files*.)

In fact it's the options that may need explanation if you're new to perl.  A bit simplified:

- the `-n` means "run this once for each line of STDIN, setting `$_` to the line"
- `-l` makes the line feed at the end of each line disappear (because otherwise that becomes part of `$_`)
- `-e` is familiar to people who know `sed`; it says this is the expression to evaluate/run.